# RCF.EXE error. Entry point not found. After upgrading to Windows 8.1

Tags: dll, windows-8.1-upgrade

After successfully upgrading to Windows 8.1 Pro with WMC,  I get a pop up window every now and then saying

```
> RCF.EXE Error - Entry Point not found.  The procedure entry point
> InternetSetCookieExW could not be located in the dynamic link library
> C:\Windows\System32\urlmon.dll
```

What is this Rcf.exe?   And how to get rid of this pop up window ?

Answer (score 0):

It was the problem with my antivirus - NetProtector.  I uninstalled it completely and reinstalled but the problem persisted.  So now I completely removed it and lo the pop up error has vanished.  The rcf.exe pertains to this antivirus only.